# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'new _reactNativeMaterialKit.MKButton.Builder')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native and using react-native-material-kit from @xinthink;
when I'm using this to create a button :

```
const LoginButton = new MKButton.Builder()
  .withBackgroundColor(MKColor.Teal)
  .withShadowRadius(2)
  .withShadowOffset({width: 0, height: 2})
  .withShadowOpacity(0.7)
  .withShadowColor('black')
  .withTextStyle({
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  })
  .withText('RAISED BUTTON')
  .build();
```

I face this error :

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'new _reactNativeMaterialKit.MKButton.Builder')

I'm sure that I've used sudo npm i -S react-native-material-kit and react-native-link;
but it doesn't seem to get solved;
I'm freaking out bcs I'm facing this for near a week;

Comment: dealin with the same issue here.  it looks like MKButton is not exported from the react-native-material-kit package.  have you found a solution to this?

Comment: AmirHosseinRnj1, @Seth Lutske, do you have fixed your issue? Please, is it possible to add the steps here?

Comment: Still no.  I think I ended up just using a different button component

Comment: @Damien I made an issue about it in the main repository; but, because no solution was provided, I decided not to use MaterialKit at all..!; I suggest you'd better use another UI library; e.g: React-Native-Elements or Native Base.

Comment: OK. Thanks. On my side I decided to downgrade to a stable version (0.5.1) and it works.